# How do I make a custom keybind for i3wm?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, arch-linux, i3-window-manager

I want to make a custom keybind that opens the i3 config for editing and I cannot get it to work:

```
bindsym $mod+Control+a exec "nano /home/mertonwu/.config/i3/config"
```

I've tried all sorts of things, including using --no-startup-id, and it doesn't throw an error with a red bar at the top, but no window opens with or without that argument.
I'm on Arch Linux btw.

Does anyone have a fix for me?

Answer (score 0):

You configured i3 itself to launch nano. This way, you won't have access to the standard input and output of the command. You should instead launch a terminal window that starts nano, which is done using a different command depending on your preferred terminal emulator.

For example, for Gnome terminal (taken from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the) post):

```
bindsym $mod+Control+a exec gnome-terminal -- nano /home/mertonwu/.config/i3/config
```

Comment: Thank you. ```bindsym $mod+Control+a exec konsole -e nano /home/mertonwu/.config/i3/config``` works perfectly for konsole.